# Access to Form to populate SP O365

Tags: list-form, access

MS licensing is so confusing to me.  Please forgive me. :)  I have created a form using Infowise and a SharePoint list.  I'd like for users outside of our organization to be able to fill out that form.  I can send the form via the web, but I'd rather they be able to login to a SharePoint page (O365) and fill it out.  Do they have to have a license for that?

Thanks in advance!
Tara

Answer (score 0):

When you use Guest invites to SPO, no those do not require licensing. [This](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/external-sharing-overview#what-happens-when-users-share) is a good reference. Search for 'license' to see restrictions, etc. on Guest access.

Comment: This is perfect!  Thank you so much.